# Is it possible to use last-child with inline styling as opposed to in a CSS file?

Tags: css, xslt, css-selectors

I am styling elements in an XSLT file, so all the styling is done here. I want to remove a border bottom from the last list element, but do not know how to apply this from within the XSLT. Here is my code:

```
                <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:text>width:120px; margin:0 auto; padding: 0; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 15px;padding-bottom: 20px; background: #6A819E; margin-top: 20px;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="ul">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                        <xsl:text>width:120px; margin:0 auto; padding: 0; background: #6A819E;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:for-each select="flights/flight"> 
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="route" />
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="route">
    <xsl:element name="li">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:text>list-style-type:none; width:120px; margin:0 auto;  margin-top: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; text-align:center; background: #6A819E;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">border: none;</xsl:if>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <a><xsl:attribute name="href">map.php?a=<xsl:value-of select="from/latitude" />&amp;b=<xsl:value-of select="from/longitude" />&amp;c=<xsl:value-of select="to/latitude" />&amp;d=<xsl:value-of select="to/longitude" />&amp;e=<xsl:value-of select="routename" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:text> text-decoration:none; color:black;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="routename" />
        </a>
    </xsl:element>
```

You can see in the list style I am applying last-child at the end, I now this is wrong but I can't think of another way to do this. Can I also ask, is this the correct way to apply styling withing an XSLT file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
 <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:text>list-style-type:none; width:120px; margin:0 auto;  margin-top: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; text-align:center;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">border: none;</xsl:if>
 </xsl:attribute>
```

You can also use CSS classes instead of using inline styling. In that case you should be able to use the last-child selector from CSS (however, this selector is not supported in IE7, IE8 (http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Alast-child).

UPDATE 1: The above would not work if there are text nodes intercalated with the route elements, so a different approach is using a different template for the last element.

```
<xsl:template match="route[last()]">
    <!-- Special behavior for last element -->
</xsl:template>
```

UPDATE 2: Another option using the if statement while ignoring all the nodes different than route would be:

```
<xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::route)">border:none;</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the code you gave me, it removes the border from all list elements, not just the bottom one. So I can still link to an external CSS file from the XSLT file then? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you just have to use the link tag on your header, as you would normally do in an HTML file.

Comment: I do not know why the above code is not working without the source code (probably something to do with text nodes between the route tags). If you post the rest of the code, I can fix the bit of code that I posted.

Comment: hey Pablo, I have added the entire code for the unordered list, I hope this can show you where it is not working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I updated the answer with a different approach. I did not reproduce your code, but the idea is not very complex.

Comment: I forgot that there is another way of doing this, in case you are interested (I've updated the answer)

Comment: Thank you I am always interested in all ways! Cheers for this!!